# Is any non symmetric matrix which is $M^*M =MM^*$?

Tags: matrices

We know $n\times n$ symmetric matrix has $n$ real eigenvalues, but I just wondering whether there are some non symmetric matrix which is $M^*M = MM^*$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are many.  We call these types of matrices [**normal matrices**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).  Two instances of these types of matrices are symmetric matrices and [**antisymmetric matrices**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_matrix).

When dealing with matrices with complex entries, the criteria change and we talk about whether a matrix is [**Hermitian or anti-Hermitian**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Such matrices are called [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) and are, among other things, characterized by being [orthonormally diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Notes), which means that their eigenvectors can be chosen in a way to form an orthonormal basis of the vector space.

Typical examples are [Hermitian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) (or, in real case, [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix)), [skew-Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix) (or, in real case, [skew-symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix)), and [unitary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) (or, in real case, [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)) matrices.